# Numpy Append Matrix to Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, append, tensor

I am trying to build a list of matrices using numpy, but when I try to append a matrix to an empty tensor, I get the error:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Concatenate and append both seem to fail. I tried calling:

`tensor = np.concatenate((tensor, matrix), axis=0)`

and

`tensor = np.append(tensor, matrix, axis=0)`

but I get the same error either way.

The tensor starts with a size of [0, h, w], and the matrix is of size [h, w]. The matrix is the correct shape in the direction I want to append to, but it won't seem to attach.

Comment: `tensor[0] = matrix`?

Comment: Initially, tensor[0] is empty and out-of-bounds. Upon adding matrix - yes.

Comment: When someone creates an array with a 0 shape, I think oh-oh.   They are building an array the slow way with repeated appends.  Use list append, and just one concatenate.  It is faster and easier to get right.

Comment: What is list append? Also, speed is not really a concern (at least at this point). I suppose I can make it a bit faster by first figuring out how many matrices I will be adding, which I might change it to later. But the issue still remained even when I had the tensor have n-rows as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `matrix` would representing the incoming ones, while you accumulate those into `tensor`. So, to solve it, add a new axis with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) as the leading one to `matrix` and then concatenate with `tensor` -

```
np.concatenate((tensor, matrix[None]),axis=0)
```

If you are accumulating, store it back into `tensor`.

Or use `np.vstack((tensor, matrix[None]))`.

Sample run -

```
In [16]: h,w = 3,4
    ...: a = np.random.rand(0,h,w)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(h,w)

In [17]: np.concatenate((a, b[None]),axis=0).shape
Out[17]: (1, 3, 4)
```